# Blender doesn't render the cloth-simulation

Tags: rendering, cloth-simulation

Blender doesn't render the cloth-simulation from the umbrella.
[.blend-file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4n23dxch4qowp4/pool.blend)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by previous cache baking. You can press *Free All Bakes* in the **Cloth Cache** panel, then give it a try.

[image]